# When TypeScript types are nested within themselves and combined with generics, how should one go about ensuring correct inference?

Tags: typescript

Currently, I have this piece of code:

```
export interface CommandArg {
  type?: 'boolean' | 'number' | 'positional' | 'string'
  alias?: string
}

export type CommandArgs = Record<string, CommandArg>

export type CommandSubs = Record<string, Command<CommandArgs, CommandSubs>>

export interface Command<
  Args extends CommandArgs,
  Subs extends CommandSubs
> {
  args?: Args
  subs?: Subs & {
    [K in keyof Subs]: Subs[K] extends Command<infer A, infer B> ? Command<A, B> : never
  }
  main?: (context: Args) => unknown
}

export function defineCommand<
  Args extends CommandArgs,
  Subs extends CommandSubs
>(command: Command<Args, Subs>) {
  return command
}

const cmd = defineCommand({
  args: {
    test: {
      type: 'boolean',
      alias: 'haha'
    }
  },
  subs: {
    haha: {
      args: {
        newTest: {
          type: 'boolean',
          alias: 'haha'
        }
      },
      main: (context) => {
        console.error(context.okok)
        console.error(context.newTest.type)
      }
    }
  },
  main: (context) => {
    console.error(context.test.type)
  }
})
```

The `context` parameter in the `cmd.main` property correctly infers its type from `cmd.args`. However, it seems that the `context` parameter in the `cmd.subs.haha.main` property cannot infer its own `cmd.subs.haha.args` type correctly. I've tried various methods, but none of them seem to work.

Comment: Are you trying to build a types file (`.d.ts`), or a typescript code (`.ts`)?

Comment: @MfyDey I'm working on a .ts file, as shown in the code above. I'm trying to encapsulate a function.